# How to get the colors of the current theme in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I am trying to change certain colors in my instance of VS Code. I know how to change colors (`"workbench.colorCustomizations"` setting + [Prop Names](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference)), but I don't know how to get the current color scheme since the value of the above-mentioned setting is `{}`.

So, the question is:
**How do I get colors of the specific part of the theme of my Visual Studio Code?**
For example a color for `gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground`, which I am trying to change.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Execute from command palette:

```
Developer: Generate Color Theme From Current Settings
```

Commented colors - the ones that get default values.

---

You can also toggle chrome console:

```
Developer: Toggle Developer Tools
```

---

Or get some colors in active editor:

```
Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes
```

Comment: And where could the "default value" be seen?

Comment: look at the key you're looking to change. if you don't have any overrides for your theme, the value in the new tab will be the default value. if you have an override in your `settings.json`, that value will show up instead, so comment out your override then re-run the command