# Finding the theme element name in Visual Studio Code to change its color

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I'm modifying a Visual Studio Code theme to my liking. However, I have problems in finding the correct element name from https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color.

Is there an extension or other way to get the specific element to modify the color? Something like "Select the element in the page to inspect it (Ctrl+Shift+C)" in Google Chrome developer console?
To be more specific, I'm trying to find the element name for this purple line to change it to a bit less aggressive color:

[image: Purple border]

Any help in finding the element name in general or in finding the name of that element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution myself with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47970668/9810067

You can open a Chrome-like developer console (It's actually identical to Chrome) by typing **"Developer: Toggle Developer Tools" into the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)**.

However, this didn't quite help me. While I was able to get the element class with "Select an element in the page to inspect it" (Ctrl+Shift+C)", I didn't manage to get the name that I could put into settings.json.

What did the trick for me was typing **"Developer: Generate Color Theme From Current Settings"** into the command palette. From there I managed to find `"editorGroup.border"`, which was just the element of which I wanted to change the color.

Then I just opened my VSCode `settings.json` (determine settings scope with the help of [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)) and added there:

```json
{
   ...
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        ...
        "editorGroup.border": "#9fb3c0ad",
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and there you have it.